# Does "non-compromised" mean the same thing as "uncompromising"?

Tags: meaning, word-difference

Example:

> Mozilla, the organization behind Firefox, is proudly non-profit, non-corporate and **non-compromised**. Will you help us work for a free and open Web for all? If everyone reading this chipped in $3, we would be supported for another year. Donate now.

Does that mean the same thing as *uncompromising*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

*Non-compromised* and *uncompromising* mean different things.

*Uncompromising* means being unwilling to compromise, usually with respect to quality or ethics. A craftsperson who is willing to work with only the best materials and reject any flaws may be considered uncompromising.

*Non-compromised* as used here likely means intact or unbroken. I think of it as an opposite to *compromised* which means something isn't functioning optimally or as intended. An example of something that could be considered compromised is a computer that has been hacked.

Comment: So, what are you saying then exactly? The Mozilla company has never been compromised by underhanded deals or anything like that? Edit your post please.

Comment: +1. The answer is a good one. The original's author must have been happy with that "clever" non-non-non parallelism. Stuck in his thumb and pulled out a plumb.   The viewpoint of the original is that for-profit commerce is by its nature motivated by greed. No shady deals required.

Comment: @CookieMonster, perhaps that is what they're trying to communicate. I think the sentence is nonsensical.

Answer (score 5):

Even to a native speaker it's not 100% obvious what they're trying to say here, except that it sounds cool.  Non-compromised would likely refer more to this definition of compromise:

> 1.
>   a. To expose or make liable to danger, suspicion, or disrepute: a secret mission that was compromised and had to be abandoned.
>
> b. To reduce in quality, value, or degree; weaken or lower: Don't 
>   compromise your standards.

As opposed to uncompromising, which is an unwillingness to cooperate.  Mozilla makes open source software, so accepting money from corporations would, to them, compromise their reputation.

Comment: Mozilla takes plenty of money from corporations who either donate to their non profit or pay them for search traffic. I'd stick with your opening sentence - it's not clear what Mozilla's trying to say here by calling themselves "non-compromised."

Comment: I mean, regardless of the truth/politics of the statement I think it's what they're going for.  But fair enough.